# Mac EC2 instance launch failure - The requested configuration is currently not supported. Please check the documentation for supported configurations

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, virtual-machines, mac

I'm trying to create a Mac EC2 instance by following this [AWS User Guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-mac-instances.html#mac-instance-launch) however it fails with the error seen in the screenshot below:

[image: EC2 Mac Error]

What I have tried so far :

- Using other AWS regions such as Ireland, Oregon with a combination of different availability zones but still received the same error message.
- Launching a Mac EC2 instance using the AWS CLI command below:

  ```
  aws ec2 allocate-hosts --region us-east-1 --instance-type mac1.metal --availability-zone us-east-1c --quantity 1 --profile syumaK
  ```

Result of the above command failed with the below message :

```
An error occurred (UnsupportedHostConfiguration) when calling the AllocateHosts operation: The requested configuration is currently not supported. Please check the documentation for supported configurations.
```

Comment: Try a different availability zone in your region, or even a different region. Sometimes new resources have very limited availability, particularly smaller regions.

Comment: I manged to resolve this issue by contacting AWS Support where they identified due to confidential reason my AWS account was not whitelisted for this feature.

Answer (score 0):

You missed the "Instance auto-placement" flag.